# Where does Homebrew put the binaries?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Does Homebrew install packages in `/usr/local/bin` by default, i.e. it puts the binaries there?

Can we tell Homebrew to put the binaries somewhere else?

Comment: how do u check what the default path for installation is?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Apple Silicon Macs (ARM)

The binaries are located at `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

### Old answer for Intel Macs

The binaries are located at `/usr/local/bin`.

From the [Homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-insist-i-install-to-usrlocal):

> Why does Homebrew insist I install to `/usr/local`?
>
> 1. **It’s easier**
>    `/usr/local/bin` is already in your
>    `PATH`.
> 2. **It’s easier**
>    Tons of build scripts break if their dependencies
>    aren’t in either `/usr` or `/usr/local`. We
>    fix this for Homebrew formulae (although we don’t always test for
>    it), but you’ll find that many RubyGems and Python setup scripts
>    break which is something outside our control.
> 3. **It’s safe**
>    Apple has left this directory for us. Which means
>    there is no `/usr/local` directory by default, so there
>    is no need to worry about messing up existing tools.
>
> **If you plan to install gems that depend on
> brews then save yourself a bunch of hassle and install to
> `/usr/local`!**
>
> It is not always straightforward to tell `gem` to look in non-standard directories for headers and libraries. If you choose `/usr/local`, many things will "just work".

You *could* change the location (aka prefix), however it's not recommended. From the [docs](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#untar-anywhere):

> However do yourself a favor and install to `/usr/local`. Some things may
> not build when installed elsewhere. One of the reasons Homebrew just
> works relative to the competition is **because** we recommend installing
> to `/usr/local`. *Pick another prefix at your peril!*
>
> ```
> mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
> ```
>
> Create a Homebrew installation wherever you extract the tarball. Whichever brew command is called is where the packages will be installed.

Comment: "Tons of build scripts break if their dependencies aren’t in either /usr or /usr/local"

Comment: How many packages have the location of Homebrew files as there dependencies? Homebrew not only wants to install in /usr/local it actually changes the ownership of the files and directories in /usr/local. This is a security issue as it removes the need for sudo to make changes to those files. The users rights may change over time, for example, the user may not remain part of the sudo group forever.

Comment: is it possible to check where hombrew is installing things to?

Comment: Re: the security issue - `/usr/local/` is intended "for use by the system administrator when installing software locally", which on a typical developers computer is the local user. While this is skirting the edge, I wouldn't say Homebrew is creating a security issue by changing the ownership of `/usr/local`.

Comment: @jamieyoung that means a malware could easily and silently replace an executable in /usr/local/bin. And with the same logic we could argue that the entire system could be turned to 777 permissions because after all the local user is most of the time the only user and the only administrator of the machine.