# When I run $brew install python3, where is the file installed?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, homebrew

when I run $brew install python3, where is this package installed? How do I locate this file?

I'm on macOS Monterey Version 12.4. unsure if it matters, but my Mac has the M1 chip.

Comment: You can find it by using the command `ls -la $(which python3)` to show to where the python3 executable in bin folder is linked to. From my machine, it is in `/usr/local/Cellar/python@<version>/<version>/bin/python3`

Comment: ...and in general, [Where does Homebrew put the binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35208494/2745495)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wondering where it's installed you can use the whereis(1) command. This will tell you the path of the python3 binary, source, and manual pages.

Example:

```
whereis python3
```

Another command you can use is the which(1) command. This will give you the full path of the shell command.

```
which python3
```